# SVG transformation from path to another

Tags: css, svg, transformation, smil

So I have this SVG animation I'm trying to make work, I made a quick smaller version of the real image below to explain what I'm trying to do.

The biggest issue I faced was making the `<line>` elements "follow" the position of the `<path>` or even `<circle>` elements.

This is the **first stage** of the animation

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 124 82">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <title>Untitled-5</title>
  <path d="M107,94a10,10,0,1,1-10,10,10,10,0,0,1,10-10m0-2a12,12,0,1,0,12,12,12,12,0,0,0-12-12Z" transform="translate(-95 -34)"/>
  <path d="M139,36a10,10,0,1,1-10,10,10,10,0,0,1,10-10m0-2a12,12,0,1,0,12,12,12,12,0,0,0-12-12Z" transform="translate(-95 -34)"/>
  <path d="M207,69a10,10,0,1,1-10,10,10,10,0,0,1,10-10m0-2a12,12,0,1,0,12,12,12,12,0,0,0-12-12Z" transform="translate(-95 -34)"/>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="38" y1="21" x2="17" y2="61"/>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="54" y1="16" x2="102" y2="40"/>
</svg>
```

Then after a few seconds I want it to smoothly animate to the positions of this next SVG. After that it should just smootly alternate between the two.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 112 68">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <title>Untitled-5</title>
  <path d="M104,53A10,10,0,1,1,94,63a10,10,0,0,1,10-10m0-2a12,12,0,1,0,12,12,12,12,0,0,0-12-12Z" transform="translate(-92 -28)"/>
  <path d="M151,74a10,10,0,1,1-10,10,10,10,0,0,1,10-10m0-2a12,12,0,1,0,12,12,12,12,0,0,0-12-12Z" transform="translate(-92 -28)"/>
  <path d="M192,30a10,10,0,1,1-10,10,10,10,0,0,1,10-10m0-2a12,12,0,1,0,12,12,12,12,0,0,0-12-12Z" transform="translate(-92 -28)"/>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="49" y1="52" x2="22" y2="39"/>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="66" y1="48" x2="92" y2="20"/>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Use SMIL to animate from one to the other. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. The problem is with the paths connecting the circles. I need a way to easily make them retain their "connection" to the the circles. I have a larger image with more circles and more paths connecting them. Therefore, transforming from one SVG to another would be incredibly helpful. Hope this made more sense.

Comment: I see no SMIL in your question. If that's what you're trying to do you should show it to us.

Comment: I didn't include any SMIL since this is not the actual SVG I tried to animate.  In the simplest from I want to move the circles and the paths connecting them to follow. Giving it the illusion that they stay connected the whole time. There's probably an easier way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to animate lines that connect the edges of the circles is going to be quite hard with SMIL animation. The endpoints will take non-linear paths across the screen.

However if you change the lines so that they connect the centre of the circles, things get **a lot** simpler.  To hide the parts of the lines that are inside the circles, you can just move them behind the circles, and then give the circles a solid fill.  Or you could use a circle mask to hide the extended lines, if you really need transparent circles.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 124 82">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-width: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <title>Untitled-5</title>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="12" y1="70" x2="44" y2="12">
    <animate attributeName="y1" from="70" to="35" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
    <animate attributeName="x2" from="44" to="59" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
    <animate attributeName="y2" from="12" to="56" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
  </line>
  <line class="cls-1" x1="44" y1="12" x2="112" y2="45">
    <animate attributeName="x1" from="44" to="59" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
    <animate attributeName="y1" from="12" to="56" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
    <animate attributeName="x2" from="112" to="100" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
    <animate attributeName="y2" from="45" to="12" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
  </line>
  <circle cx="12" cy="70" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate attributeName="cy" from="70" to="35" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="44" cy="12" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate attributeName="cx" from="44" to="59" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
    <animate attributeName="cy" from="12" to="56" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
  </circle>
  <circle cx="112" cy="45" r="11" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
    <animate attributeName="cx" from="112" to="100" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
    <animate attributeName="cy" from="45" to="12" dur="2s" fill="freeze"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow! I never thought of that. Thanks a lot!